# Server error 500 when accessing api controller through Load balancer in AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-rds, amazon-elb

I have a loadbalancer. I can access my other controllers. But there is one controller which doesn't work and is connected to the database. When I enter the DNS link in the browser and put /api/Albums after, it tells me an internal server error. When I run my application locally without the load balancer I can see the table values though. It does work locally. What am I doing wrong? Here is my controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class AlbumsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAlbumService _albumService;

        public AlbumsController(AlbumContext context)
        {
            _albumService = new AlbumService(context);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves all albums
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>All albums</returns>
        /// <response code="201">Returns the newly created item</response>
        /// <response code="400">If the item is null</response> 
        [HttpGet]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Models.Album>>> GetAlbums()
        {
            return await _albumService.GetAll();
        }
```

I use the Blue/Green service for the load balancer.

These are my Cloudwatch logs

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   timestamp   |                                                                                                               message                                                                                                                |
|---------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1625123996583 | [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]                                                                                                                                              |
| 1625123996584 |       An error occurred using the connection to database 'albumdatabase' on server 'tcp://cnsd-db-107600463818.crwjsnt1krlv.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432'.                                                                       |
| 1625123996584 | [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]                                                                                                                                                            |
| 1625123996584 |       An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for context type 'Album.Api.Models.AlbumContext'.                                                                                                            |
| 1625123996584 |       System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.                                                                                                                      |
| 1625123996584 |        ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while connecting                                                                                                                                                          |
| 1625123996584 |        ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt                                                                                                                                                               |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                                                          |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                                                |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                                                   |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                  |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<>c__DisplayClass38_0.<<Rent>g__RentAsync|0>d.MoveNext()                                                                                                                                            |
| 1625123996584 |       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---                                                                                                                                                                              |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<<Open>g__OpenAsync|0>d.MoveNext()                                                                                                                                         |
| 1625123996584 |       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---                                                                                                                                                                              |
| 1625123996584 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                |
| 1625123996584 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                |
| 1625123996584 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)                                                                                        |
| 1625123996584 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                        |
| 1625123996584 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                          |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                 |
| 1625123996584 |          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                 |
| 1625123996584 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()                                                                                                                  |
| 1625123996584 |       System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.                                                                                                                      |
| 1625123996584 |        ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while connecting                                                                                                                                                          |
| 1625123996584 |        ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt                                                                                                                                                               |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                                                          |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                                                |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                                                   |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                  |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<>c__DisplayClass38_0.<<Rent>g__RentAsync|0>d.MoveNext()                                                                                                                                            |
| 1625123996584 |       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---                                                                                                                                                                              |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<<Open>g__OpenAsync|0>d.MoveNext()                                                                                                                                         |
| 1625123996584 |       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---                                                                                                                                                                              |
| 1625123996584 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                |
| 1625123996584 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                |
| 1625123996584 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)                                                                                        |
| 1625123996584 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                        |
| 1625123996584 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                          |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                 |
| 1625123996584 |          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| 1625123996584 |          at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                 |
| 1625123996584 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()                                                                                                                  |
| 1625123996587 | [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]                                                                                                                                                               |
| 1625123996587 |       Connection id "0HM9S0VI1LE4Q", Request id "0HM9S0VI1LE4Q:00000005": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.                                                                                                      |
| 1625123996587 |       System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.                                                                                                                      |
| 1625123996587 |        ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while connecting                                                                                                                                                          |
| 1625123996587 |        ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt                                                                                                                                                               |
| 1625123996587 |          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                                                          |
| 1625123996587 |          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                                                |
| 1625123996587 |          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                                                   |
| 1625123996587 |          at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                  |
| 1625123996587 |          at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<>c__DisplayClass38_0.<<Rent>g__RentAsync|0>d.MoveNext()                                                                                                                                            |
| 1625123996587 |       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---                                                                                                                                                                              |
| 1625123996587 |          at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass41_0.<<Open>g__OpenAsync|0>d.MoveNext()                                                                                                                                         |
| 1625123996587 |       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---                                                                                                                                                                              |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                                |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)                                                                                        |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                        |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(DbContext _, Boolean result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                          |
| 1625123996587 |          at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                 |
| 1625123996587 |          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| 1625123996587 |          at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                 |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()                                                                                                                  |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                          |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)                                                                          |
| 1625123996587 |          at Album.Api.AlbumService.GetAll() in C:\Users\dvide\album-api\Album-Api\Album.Api\AlbumService.cs:line 65                                                                                                                  |
| 1625123996587 |          at Album.Api.Controllers.AlbumsController.GetAlbums() in C:\Users\dvide\album-api\Album-Api\Album.Api\Controllers\AlbumsController.cs:line 39                                                                               |
| 1625123996587 |          at lambda_method5(Closure , Object )                                                                                                                                                                                        |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)                 |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)                                             |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)                                                                                                             |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)                                                                                     |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)      |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)                   |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)                                                                              |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)                                                                                     |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)                                                                                                                                   |
| 1625123996587 |          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)                                                                                            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: seems like your application cannot connect to the database. See the `Timeout during connection attempt ` in the logs. Can you provide information where you deploy to (Lambda, EKS/ECS, EC2) in AWS and where your database is running?

Comment: My Database is running in RDS on port 5432, I have a Blue/Green Service running through the Load Balancer with two target groups.

Comment: A connection timeout might happen if your service cannot reach your database over the network. Make sure that there are no NACLS or Security Groups which would block your service from accessing RDS. As you are saying that it works from local: are you connecting to RDS via internet or is there a VPN connection? If it's internet I recommend moving the database into a private subnet.